# Installed SSL Certificate to one of my domains in plesk, but it does not work

Tags: https, plesk

I installed certificate to one of my domains in plesk. But when ever i try to visit https://domain.com it gives can not find server error. Where as http:// works just fine. I installed Comodo certificate and followed the exact guide they provided me over chat, i also compared the guide with other tutorials listed on google, such as namecheap etc. But all result in same manner. I am running a Dedicated Server with Plesk v12.x.x